# REST API Call Journey through Postman

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I'm trying to make an API call through POSTMAN to trigger a journey, but when I doing that I am getting

> Error: 596 Service Not Found

PostMan Call:

**Host:** `https://************.rest.marketingcloudapis.com`

**POST** `/interaction/v1/events`

**Content-Type:** `application/json`

**Authorization:** `7La9cWaJExSh6G1ogJi2P8o1`

```
{
    "ContactKey": "1231221",
    "EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent-73c695fc-8a4c-30a3-5f4a-72b91a159e35",
    "Data": {
        "Email":"*****vig@gmail.com",
        "SubscriberKey":"******vig@gmail.com"}
}
```

Can someone help in same.

Thanks

Praneet

Comment: is it possible to update the record in DE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
 EndppoinURl: https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/events
 Content-Type: application/json
 Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

  this is request
 {
"ContactKey": "YOUR_CONTACTS_KEY",
"EventDefinitionKey":"EVENT_DEFINITION_KEY_OF_API_EVENT",
"EstablishContactKey": true,
"Data": {
    "Email":"*****vig@gmail.com",
    "SubscriberKey":"******vig@gmail.com"
}
```

}

Comment: Hi @pkharries Thanks for your help. I am able to send through above attribute but I have to add the ContactKey same as SubscirberKey or else it creates a seprate row fir contact key record.

Answer (score 2):

@praneet- In the case of a 596 error, it will be an issue with the URL used to call the API is almost every case. Please confirm once the URL again.

Comment: how to update the record in journey builder api event

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when the `ACCESS_TOKEN` has expired or has not been included in the `Authorization`.

You call should include

```
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy--my question is  I am inserting same record using postman for trigger the journey this time need to update the record in DE is it possible